# Increase the character length of Comments in Case Comment

Tags: case, case-comment

Is there a way to increase the character length of Case Comments according to the latest release ?

I know this was not possible few years back. Is it still the case?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Case comment character limit is 4000 and if that is encrypted then character limit will be 2959 characters.

If you need more characters then create a separate object, link to Case object and create long text area according to your desire limit.